# FlexRender Functional Component Tanstack React Table v8

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am rebuilding a react-table to v8 where one cell is a functional component, which shows the status, based on the Id value.

My Status component is defined like this:

```js
function Status({ id }) {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("pending");
  useEffect(() => {
    getApi(`/status/${id}`).then((stat) => {
      setStatus(stat);
    });
  }, []);
  return status == "pending" ? (
    <p>Pending</p>
  ) : (
    <p>{status}</p>
  );
}
```

The column is defined like this:

```js
columnHelper.accessor("id", {
      header: () => "Latest Status",
      cell: (info) =>  <Status id={info.getValue()} />
```

For rendering the cell I am using FlexRender

```js
flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell,cell.getContext())
```

With this, I get only the "Pending" when the cell renders, the state on the component is not getting updated, even after the API provides the response.

I had the same concept on React-Table v7 using `cell.render("Cell")` and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

flexRender is creating a new component instead of re-rendering it. I would suggest you wrap it under useMemo so that react keep track of the previously created reference or just try to implement your own logic like if cell.column.columnDef.cell is a react component or not and render it accordingly.

Comment: Can you give more informations about memoizing flexRender? `const memoizedFlexRender = useMemo(() => flexRender, [])` does not work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and turned out to be my `columns` and `defaultColumn` definitions were out of components so they were not reinitialized on data change (Probably keeps the old value in the memory or something like that, i don't know how it works internally)

```
const columns = [
    columnHelper.accessor('phone', {
      cell: info => (
        <span>
          {info.getValue()}
        </span >
      )
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor('name', {}),
    columnHelper.accessor('email', {})
]

const defaultColumn: Partial<ColumnDef<TypeHere>> = {
    cell: function Cell({ getValue, row: { index }, column, table }) {
      const initialValue = getValue()
      const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue)

      const onBlur = async () => {
        // ...
      }

      return (
        <input
          value={(value ?? '').toString()}
          onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
          onBlur={onBlur}
        />
      )
    }
}
```

These above column definitions that are passed to `useReactTable` were defined on top of my file, which is outside of component function. When i moved them inside the component it worked.

Or instead of all these, just include this piece of code to `defaultColumn` before return. No need to move your definitions inside component.

```
useEffect(() => {
   setValue(initialValue)
}, [initialValue])
```